# tortoise.exceptions.OperationalError: column <some column> of relation <some table> does not exist error

Tags: python, fastapi, tortoise-orm

I'm trying to use `aerich` with `tortoise` to manage migration with sqlite.
And when I `aerich upgrade` after `aerich migrate --name some_migration`(this seemed successfully created a migration file), I got this error.

```
tortoise.exceptions.OperationalError: column <some column> of relation <some table> does not exist
```

What I have changed was just deleting a column to test.

```
from tortoise.models import Model
from tortoise import fields

class User(Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    username = fields.CharField(50, unique=True, null=False)
    # some_column = fields.CharField(50, null=False) # just delete this one to check if migration works
```

The migration file looks like this.

```
-- upgrade --
ALTER TABLE "user" DROP COLUMN "some_column";
-- downgrade --
ALTER TABLE "user" ADD "some_column" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL;
```

Could someone help me on this?

Comment: You mention both postgres and sqlite .. did you perform the migration for both services with the correct connection string?

Comment: Thank you and yes it's confusing so I deleted the postgres part. I have the problem with sqlite. And yes it has correct connection.

Comment: Have a similar problem, @user3368526 did you solve the issue ?